# Filter array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am creating a project using JavaScript. I am stuck in the problem while filtering the array of object: Here is the array:

```
var arr1 = [{
      "name": "harkaran",
      "lname": "sofat",
      "userId": 49,
     "postedUserId": 52,
      "id": 21,

    },{
      "name": "harkaran",
      "lname": "sofat",
      "userId": 49,
      "postedUserId": 57,
      "id": 21,
    }]
```

final array should look like:

```
[{
    "name": "harkaran",
      "lname": "sofat",
      "userId": 49,
     "postedUserId": 52,
      "id": 21,
      postedUsers:[52,57]
}]
```

I  am trying to creating new object. Here is the approach i am using.But dont know how can i achieve this
var arr =[]
    let obj = {}

```
        obj['name'] = "";
        obj['lname'] = "";
        obj['userId'] = "";
        obj['postedUserId'] = "";
        obj['id'] = "";
        obj['postedUsers'] = [];
        arr.push(obj);

        for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){


         }
```

Comment: Why is there a `postedUserId` in the final answer?

Comment: postedUserId is unique.

Comment: So the first one stays, and the first *and* all the rest go into the array?

Comment: yes...........@ Jack Bashford

Comment: OK, edited my answer, how does that look?

Comment: your answer working fine....Thanks

Comment: I want using for loop....

Comment: You want to compare all the properties or just `id`

Comment: only id needs to be compared..

Comment: *"...I want using for loop..."*: if you have such requirements, please make sure to put that in the question, including the reason why. Not everyone reads these comments.

Comment: I thinking, you don`t writing specialized function for this structure. You can writing common uselly function for grouping. As this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce`:

```js
var arr1 = [{"name":"harkaran","lname":"sofat","userId":49,"postedUserId":52,"id":21,},{"name":"harkaran","lname":"sofat","userId":49,"postedUserId":57,"id":21,}];
const res = Object.values(arr1.reduce((acc, { postedUserId, name, ...rest }) => {
  acc[name] = acc[name] || { name, ...rest, postedUserId, postedUsers: [] };
  acc[name].postedUsers = [].concat(acc[name].postedUsers, postedUserId);
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is not called filtering. Its called **grouping**. You can do that in following steps:

- First use `reduce()` on array and set accumulator to an empty object `{}`
- During each iteration get `id` and `postedUserId` is separate variable using Destructuring. And use spread operator to get rest of properties.
- Then check if is there already an item present of the current `id` in accumulator.
- If its there then push the `postedUserId` to its `postedUsers` array.
- If that key is not present then set the key(`id`) on accumulator to an object with `postedUsers` as empty array.

```js
var arr1 = [{"name":"harkaran","lname":"sofat","userId":49,"postedUserId":52,"id":21,},{"name":"harkaran","lname":"sofat","userId":49,"postedUserId":57,"id":21,}];

const res = arr1.reduce((ac,{id,postedUserId,...rest}) => {
  if(!ac[id]) ac[id] = {id,postedUserId,postedUsers:[],...rest};
  ac[id].postedUsers.push(postedUserId);
  return ac;

},{})

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

You  asked in the comments for simple `for` loop so here is the version of that.

```js
var arr1 = [{"name":"harkaran","lname":"sofat","userId":49,"postedUserId":52,"id":21,},{"name":"harkaran","lname":"sofat","userId":49,"postedUserId":57,"id":21,}];

let res = {};

for(let i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  let {id,postedUserId,...rest} = arr1[i];
  if(!res[id]) res[id] = {id,postedUserId,postedUsers:[],...rest};
  res[id].postedUsers.push(postedUserId);
}

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: You missed `postedUserId` in final output mate

Comment: @CodeManiac You are right but I consider OP had put that mistakenly. Because there is no point to have `postedUserId` when there is an array of `postedUsers`

Comment: that's clearly mentioned by OP in comments so i pointed out [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512709/filter-array-of-object-in-javascript/56512807#comment99611827_56512709)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and group the `postedUser` and keep the first `postedUserId`

- First loop through `arr1` array and use `id` as key on object we are building
- First we check for the id if the `object` already has value, than check for `postedUserId` if it's not there add the current id else don't
- Now push the `postedUserId` in `postedUser`
- Get the values from final in the end

```js
var arr1 = [{"name": "harkaran","lname": "sofat","userId": 49,"postedUserId": 52,"id": 21,}, {"name": "harkaran","lname": "sofat","userId": 49,"postedUserId": 57,"id": 21,}]

let final = arr1.reduce((op,{id,...rest})=>{
  let postedUserId = rest.postedUserId
  if(op[id] && op[id].postedUserId){
    delete rest.postedUserId
  }
  op[id] = op[id] || {...rest,postedUser:[]}
  op[id].postedUser.push(postedUserId)
  return op
},{})

console.log(Object.values(final))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a temporary `Map` for the grouping you want.

```js
var arr1 = [{"name":"harkaran","lname":"sofat","userId":49,"postedUserId":52,"id":21,},{"name":"harkaran","lname":"sofat","userId":49,"postedUserId":57,"id":21,}];

const map = new Map(arr1.map(o => [o.id, { ...o, postUsersId: [] }]));
arr1.forEach(o => map.get(o.id).postUsersId.push(o.postedUserId));
const res = [...map.values()];

console.log(res);
```

This will give precedence to the data given with the *last* occurrence of the same id. If you want the *first* to have precedence, then just reverse the array